# Not able to codesign exe using signtool through ssh connection windows server 2012 R2

Tags: code-signing, openssh, signtool

I am trying to codesign a exe by using signtool, the successful codesign has the below logs

```
The following certificates were considered:
Issued to: **

    Issued by: ******
    
    Expires:  ******
    
    SHA1 hash: ******

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Subject Name filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
The following certificate was selected:
Issued to: ****

    Issued by: ******
    
    Expires:   ******
    
    SHA1 hash: ******

Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: ntnxcollector-service.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1

Number of warnings: 0

Number of errors: 0
```

When I try to codesign using ssh connection to the PC the logs are

```
The following certificate was selected:
Issued to: ****
Issued by: **
Expires:   **
SHA1 hash: ***

Done Adding Additional Store
```

I tried with different options of signtool but nothing worked

I tried with different options of signtool but nothing worked, also tried with bash file on the local of PC locally on terminal everything is working fine

signtool command I use :

```
signtool sign /debug /a /sm /n "**" /t http://timestamp.digicert.com **.exe
```

Connection to localhost

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -t WINDOWS_USER@IP
```